# Couchbase - get all document prefixes

Tags: couchbase, sql++

We have a fairly large couchbase bucket that holds several document types, denoted by document prefixes. For example, we have some documents prefixed with `device---[document name]`, some with `market---[document name]`). I want a list of all the existing prefixes. This is what I have tried so far:

```
select split(meta().id, "---")[0] as doc_type
from configs
group by doc_type;
```

I would hope for it to return something like

```
[
  {
    "doc_type": "device"
  },
  {
    "doc_type": "market"
  },
]
```

It fails with

```
"code": 4210, 
"msg": "Expression must be a group key or aggregate: (split((meta(`docsis_configs`).`id`), \"---\")[0])",
```

I'm not sure how to solve the aggregation problem and have tried various things. However I suspect that even if I got that to work, this query would be very inefficient. Can someone help me with the aggregation? And is there a smarter way to do this? Or is this fine?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the Eventing Service below is some simple code that will create a counter document for each unique prefix. This will update a counter for every document you have.

Note dst_bkt is a bucket binding to a different bucket in r+w mode this bucket should start out empty it will get a doc per prefix with the counts.

This will also work without and indexes.

```
function OnUpdate(doc, meta) {
    var pfx =  meta.id.split("---");
    if (!pfx[1]) return; // bad key so return and skip
    couchbase.increment(dst_bkt,{"id": pfx[0] });
}
```

Note, there is a non standard hack to improve the performance drastically if you only want to run this as a one off tool (no counts) if interested please DM me.

Answer (score 2):

Only projection alias can be referenced in ORDER BY.

```
select doc_type
from configs
LET doc_type = split(meta().id, "---")[0]
group by doc_type;
```

OR

```
select doc_type
from configs
group by split(meta().id, "---")[0] AS doc_type;
```

There is no other way to achieve this with N1QL.

If you want you can use couchbase map reduce views (https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/views/views-intro.html)

Also eventing service might be option.